# unable to use where-object as value is nested in array with powershell

Tags: json, powershell, sharepoint, contains, where-object

I'm currently working through a csv of Sharepoint AuditData and trying to evaluate several fields that are nested in the audit data field.
I've tried all the Usual $_.AuditData.CreatedDate etc. but can't figure out how to query the data thats nested in it.
It's my first time trying to evaluate against data thats structured like this and any help about how best to go about this would be very much appreciated.

I've tried the where object clause and its not returning the data I would expect

```
"PSComputerName","RunspaceId","PSShowComputerName","RecordType","CreationDate","UserIds","Operations","AuditData","ResultIndex","ResultCount","Identity","IsValid","ObjectState"
"REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","{""AppAccessContext"":{""AADSessionId"":""REDACTED"",""CorrelationId"":""REDACTED"",""TokenIssuedAtTime"":""REDACTED"",""UniqueTokenId"":""REDACTED""},""CreationTime"":""REDACTED"",""Id"":""REDACTED"",""Operation"":""REDACTED"",""OrganizationId"":""REDACTED"",""RecordType""REDACTED""UserKey"":""REDACTED"",""UserType""REDACTED""Version""REDACTED""Workload"":""REDACTED"",""ClientIP"":""REDACTED"",""ObjectId"":""REDACTED"",""UserId"":""REDACTED"",""CorrelationId"":""REDACTED"",""EventSource"":""REDACTED"",""ItemType"":""REDACTED""",""ListId"":""REDACTED"",""ListItemUniqueId"":""REDACTED"",""Site"":""REDACTED"",""UserAgent"":""REDACTED"",""WebId"":"REDACTED"",""MachineId"":""REDACTED"",""FileSyncBytesCommitted"":""REDACTED"",""HighPriorityMediaProcessing""REDACTED""ImplicitShare"":""REDACTED"",""IsManagedDevice""REDACTED""SourceFileExtension"":""REDACTED"",""SiteUrl"":""REDACTED"",""SourceFileName"":""REDACTED"",""SourceRelativeUrl"":""REDACTED""}","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED"
```

Comment: Please add a sanitized sample of the CSV and specify what the expected outcome should be.

Comment: "*csv of Sharepoint AuditData*". `Csv` ([Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) data is flat by design. Anyways, to find the members (properties) of your `$AuditData`, try: `$AuditData |Get-Member`, or to see the whole structure: `$AuditData |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5`.

Comment: Show us the CSV :)

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure how to upload the csv file so i've added the sanitized csv as a code snippet, 
It's fields inside the audit data field i'm trying to evaluate such as operation, record type etc.
Thank you all for you quick responses

Comment: Aha, so it's JSON! Use `$_.AuditData |ConvertFrom-Json` to parse the embedded data

Comment: Boom and just like that I can play with the data, thank you so much!